# What is the benefit of using a context mananger with multiprocessing.Manager?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, contextmanager

In [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#customized-managers), Manager is used with a context manager (i.e. `with`) like so:

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

class MathsClass:
    def add(self, x, y):
        return x + y
    def mul(self, x, y):
        return x * y

class MyManager(BaseManager):
    pass

MyManager.register('Maths', MathsClass)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with MyManager() as manager:
        maths = manager.Maths()
        print(maths.add(4, 3))         # prints 7
        print(maths.mul(7, 8))         # prints 56
```

But what is the benefit of this, with the exception of the namespace? For opening file streams, the benefit is quite obvious in that you don't have to manually `.close()` the connection, but what is it for Manager? If you don't use it in a context, what steps do you have to use to ensure that everything is closed properly?

In short, what is the benefit of using the above over something like:

```
manager = MyManager()
maths = manager.Maths()
print(maths.add(4, 3))         # prints 7
print(maths.mul(7, 8))         # prints 56
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But what is the benefit of this (...)?

First, you get the primary benefit of almost any context managers.  You have a well-defined lifetime for the resource.  It is allocated and acquired when the `with ...:` block is opened.  It is released when the blocks ends (either by reaching the end or because an exception is raised).  It is still deallocated whenever the garbage collector gets around to it but this is of less concern since the external resource has already been released.

In the case of `multiprocessing.Manager` (which is a function that returns a `SyncManager`, even though `Manager` looks lot like a class), the resource is a "server" process that holds state and a number of worker processes that share that state.

> what is [the benefit of using a context manager] for Manager?

If you don't use a context manager and you don't call shutdown on the manager then the "server" process will continue running until the `SyncManager`'s `__del__` is run.  In some cases, this might happen soon after the code that created the `SyncManager` is done (for example, if it is created inside a short function and the function returns normally and you're using CPython then the reference counting system will probably quickly notice the object is dead and call its `__del__`).  In other cases, it might take longer (if an exception is raised and holds on to a reference to the manager then it will be kept alive until that exception is dealt with).  In some bad cases, it might never happen at all (if `SyncManager` ends up in a reference cycle then its `__del__` will prevent the cycle collector from collecting it *at all*; or your process might crash before `__del__` is called).  In all these cases, you're giving up control of when the extra Python processes created by `SyncManager` are cleaned up.  These processes may represent non-trivial resource usage on your system.  In really bad cases, if you create `SyncManager` in a loop, you may end up creating many of these that live at the same time and could easily consume huge quantities of resources.

> If you don't use it in a context, what steps do you have to use to ensure that everything is closed properly?

You have to implement the context manager protocol yourself, as you would for any context manager you used without `with`.  It's tricky to do in pure-Python while still being correct.  Something like:

```
manager = None
try:
    manager = MyManager()
    manager.__enter__()
    # use it ...
except:
    if manager is not None:
        manager.__exit__(*exc_info())
else:
    if manager is not None:
        manager.__exit__(None, None, None)
```

`start` and `shutdown` are also aliases of `__enter__` and `__exit__`, respectively.

Comment: The question arose because I saw many code fragments that just initialized the manager (`manager = Manager()`) but never did  anything to *exit* the mananger (as in my final example). I understand that with a with-block, you clean up the garbage automatically, but is closing/exiting the Manager explicitly necessary if you do not use a context manager? What is the consequence of not doing `manager.__exit__`?

Comment: added another paragraph that discusses that more directly

Comment: Thank you. A final question (might be better suited for a separate question?): can Manager and Pool be used by the same context manager? Is there a priority that needs to be taken into account? `with Pool(12) as pool, Manager() as manager` or the other way around? Or doesn't it matter?

Comment: Yea, seems like a different question to me.  I'm not sure how Manager and Pool interact, exactly, and I don't find the docs to be all that clear.  I *assume* you can do something like that `with` statement but exactly what it _does_ I don't know. ;)

Comment: Great answer! Although I think that you wouldn't use `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` manually if you are not using the context manager. You probably would just use `start()` then, and call `shutdown()` in a `finally` clause. However, this depends on what the context manager does, of course (for files it's different than for this case). But your example could clearly demonstrates the general working of the context manager :-)